# Nice applications of estimation theory and hypothesis testing

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, applications, parameter-estimation, hypothesis-testing

As a mathematics professor in an engineeer school, I want to write some lab work for students in Statistics. This work should last four hours and will be made in a language such as Matlab or Python.

Therefore, I am looking for nice applications of Statistics, in particular estimation theory, or hypothesis testing (potentially regression).

I thought of:

- restoration of a blurred image with noise (based on the method of maximum likelihood)
- problems in signal detection.

Are you aware of other applications?

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure this is exactly what you're looking for, but here are 2 topics that might be intresting:

- Multi-sensor data fusion: Bayesian approach ([example](https://www-sigproc.eng.cam.ac.uk/foswiki/pub/Main/OP205/mphil.pdf))
- [Blind source separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_signal_separation)

For the multi-sensor data fusion I can recommnend 'Multi-Sensor Data Fusion: An Introduction' by Mitchell, H.B as a source of information.